# Can not apply EAP pattern to WCF Service Client on Windows Phone 8

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-8

I am trying to apply EAP pattern to call WCF service. Same code runs smoothly on Windows Console Application but hangs on indefinetely on Task.Wait on Windows Phone application.

Any ideas about the problem will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

**Here is the extension method and helper function:**

```
public static class ServiceExtensions
{
    public static Task<string> DoGlobalizationResourcesInquiryAsyncTask(
        this Service1Client serviceClient,
        int request)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
        EventHandler<GetDataCompletedEventArgs> handler = null;
        handler = (sender, e) => EAPHelpers.TransferCompletion(
            tcs,
            e,
            () => e.Result,
            () => serviceClient.GetDataCompleted -= handler);

        serviceClient.GetDataCompleted += handler;
        try
        {
            serviceClient.GetDataAsync(request, tcs);
        }
        catch
        {
            serviceClient.GetDataCompleted -= handler;
            tcs.TrySetCanceled();
            throw;
        }

        return tcs.Task;

    }
}

public static class EAPHelpers
{
    public static void TransferCompletion<T>(
        TaskCompletionSource<T> tcs,
        AsyncCompletedEventArgs e,
        Func<T> getResult,
        Action unregisterHandler)
    {
        if (e.UserState == tcs)
        {
            if (e.Cancelled) tcs.TrySetCanceled();
            else if (e.Error != null) tcs.TrySetException(e.Error);
            else tcs.TrySetResult(getResult());
            if (unregisterHandler != null) unregisterHandler();
        }
    }
}
```

**I call the extension method as follows:**

```
        Service1Client client = new Service1Client();
        var task = client.DoGlobalizationResourcesInquiryAsyncTask(3);
        task.Wait();
        var response = task.Result;
```